# Why would REGEXP_REPLACE throw an untranslatable character ? Is this a bug?

Tags: teradata

I have a huge table `testTable`. I am trying to clean `txt` column by leaving only letters and spaces.

Here is what I do

```
SELECT id_cd, REGEXP_REPLACE(txt, '[^a-zA-Z ]', '', 1, 0, 'i') new_txt 
FROM testTable
```

The above query throws `String contains an untranslatable character`. I don't know which row it fails at because the table is huge.

When I limit the number of rows to some small number, it works, so the query syntax is fine.

```
 SELECT TOP 10 id_cd, REGEXP_REPLACE(txt, '[^a-zA-Z ]', '', 1, 0, 'i') new_txt 
 FROM testTable
```

Is this a bug ? How can I spot the row it fails ? Why would it fail in the first place ?

---

I also tried the following :

```
SELECT id_cd, REGEXP_REPLACE(TRANSLATE(txt using unicode_to_latin), '[^a-zA-Z ]', '', 1, 0, 'i') new_txt 
 FROM testTable
```

But also got the same error .

Comment: use with error option in your translate function .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have same issue at the start of the year .
You can find these characters using translate_chk function which returns 0 if success else non zero character.
We handled like below

```
case when  translate_chk(d.column using  latin_to_unicode)  <> '0'
  then 0
  else Instr(d.column  , 'E3S')
  end column
```

But in that case we were not  cared about the lost data , we loaded 0 for that.
Hope it helps..

Comment: Thank you. one question :  why are you using latin_to _unicode ? i thought unicode_to_latin was less inclusive

Comment: By default system creates columns with latin character set .We were doing migration from oracle , so while loading we found data is having Unicode .That's why we did it..and but we must have to be sure about it as unicode comes with cost of extra space.